# React Native - Expo: Schedule App Background Launch at Specific Time

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-notifications, background-process

I'm working on a React Native project using Expo, and as per my client's request, I'm looking for a way to schedule the app to open in the background at a specific time, similar to a push notification schedule; my client wants the app to trigger an app launch in the background, at least only with Android.

I've explored the Expo Notifications API, and it seems to do the job by scheduling local push notifications, but my client wants to trigger background app launches.

Is there a specific module or approach within Expo that allows for scheduling the app to open in the background at a specified time? Do I have to use Native Code? If so, where can I start?

Answer (score 1):

While you can't directly schedule a background task in React Native, you can achieve it using Android's JobScheduler.

React Native itself doesn't offer a built-in solution, so here are two common approaches:

**Native Module**:
Create a [native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) in Android that uses Android JobScheduler API. This involves writing native code and exposing its functionality to JavaScript.

**3rd Party Library**:
Alternatively, you can use third-party libraries specifically designed for background task scheduling in React Native. check out [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task).
Choose the approach that best fits your project requirements and development preferences."

An example of how to use native module

```
// App.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import YourJobSchedulerModule from './YourJobSchedulerModule';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Schedule the job when the component mounts
    YourJobSchedulerModule.scheduleJob();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Your React Native App</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;


// YourJobSchedulerModule.js

import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { YourJobSchedulerModule } = NativeModules;

export default YourJobSchedulerModule;


// YourPackageModule.java
package com.yourapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class YourPackageModule implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new YourJobSchedulerModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}


// YourJobSchedulerModule.java

package com.yourapp;

import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class YourJobSchedulerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public YourJobSchedulerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "YourJobSchedulerModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void scheduleJob() {
        // Implement your JobScheduler logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't what I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: @Juan What exactly are you looking for?. You can use a job scheduler to run job intent service which is a background service and runs without opening the android in foreground.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Android/Java so do you have some boilerplate example that I can use for React Native's Native Module and Android's JobScheduler API?

Comment: have a look at example. You need to implement it based on your specifications